# Corda Firewall - float

Tags: firewall

I am trying to setup the [Corda Firewall](https://docs.corda.r3.com/bridge-configuration-file.html), specifically the float. What doesn't seem to be clear is what is required and only required on this server/container. Trying with just the corda-bridgeserver.jar with relevant other files just errors.

I am not 100% sure what files are supposed to be on the float. I have:

```
emp-float/bridge.conf
emp-float/corda-bridgeserver-3.1.jar
emp-float/network-parameters (copied from bridge inner)
emp-float/ floatcerts/float.jks  
emp-float/floatcerts/trust.jks
```

I run:

```
java -jar corda-bridgeserver-3.1.jar
```

and get the following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by Capsule (file:/home/b3iadmin/emp-float/corda-bridgeserver-3.1.jar) to field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.mbsInterceptor
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of Capsule
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1024)
        at net.corda.bridge.internal.BridgeStartup.enforceSingleBridgeIsRunning(BridgeStartup.kt:147)
        at net.corda.bridge.internal.BridgeStartup.run(BridgeStartup.kt:48)
        at net.corda.bridge.Bridge.main(Bridge.kt:19)
```

I am new to Linux so any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuan,

This appears to be an issue with permissioning. Please ensure that your user has write access to all directories under `emp-float`. Also, please update the version of the Bridge/Float component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things to resolve the issue:

1. Installed JDK version 8 as this is the version Corda runs on
2. Adjusted permissions
3. Used version 3.2 of Corda bridge/float